# Absolute path for view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two MVC projects, they both share the exact same views, and the same controller name as well.
Currently I have duplicates of these views in both projects, I would like the option to "share" these views by putting them outside these projects and have the ViewEnhines point to that location.

Is this possible ? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using VS 2015 a [shared project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/) that has the views might be the best option. I have not tested so not sure how well it would work in this scenario but it is worth a try.

Comment: @Igor Try to use dll file instead of creating new project. It's easier.

Comment: Igor, I created a shared project, how do I go about accessing the folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using Html Helper. Creating a dll file what will be shared via 2 projects, then calling it.

Reference link: [Creating Custom HTML Helpers (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Something you can do in the View of per project looks like:

```
@Html.MyShareView(model)
```